# How to Get Text from Textboxes and Drop-down Lists and save them in a .csi file then send them to a specified Outlook or G-mail?

Tags: html, email, web, input

So, I am making a Complaint Box Online for a Company, However, This is it's image right now :-
[image]

The problem is, That `<button></button>` Down there should Read all of these Textboxes (Please Include Drop-down lists) and It should send their input to a specified Outlook or G-mail.
But I am just an intermediate and I don't really understand e-mailing and reading inputs.
That's my Code so far :-

```
<p style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">Do you have a Complaint ?, We're Happy to Hear it :</p>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><b><label style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">Name : </label></b></td> <td><input type="text" style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b><label style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">Phone Number : </label></b></td> <td><input type="text" style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b><label style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">WhatsApp Number (Optional) : </label></b></td> <td><input type="text" style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b><label style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">E-mail : </label></b></td> <td><input type="text" style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b><label style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">Company Title : </label></b></td> <td><input type="text" style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b><label style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">Complaint Title : </label></b></td> <td><input type="text" style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b><label style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;">Details :- : </label></b></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <textarea style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:25px; color:#E25937;" rows="7" cols="56"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button style="font-family: tahoma; font-size:50px; background-color:#E25937; color:#FFFFFF; width: 200px; height: 74px;">Send</button>
```

also, I want these inputs to be in a .csi file.
So, can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Any body here ?

Comment: Which technology are you using to send emails, I mean like PHP.

Comment: Well, I have python, JS, PHP, and I don't know what to do or use, these files are all HTML files

Comment: which one you think is the best ?

Comment: ok so if you use PHP I will show an example for this,

Comment: And please define name for every field, like <textarea name="comment"></textarea>, you can use any name to the field.

Comment: Well, I will suggest PHP.

Comment: hmmm, text areas and boxes, we need to get their input and then send it to a person

Comment: I don't want my HTML files to be lost , PHP is fine btw

Comment: also, I want these inputs to first be saved in a .csi file then being sent

Comment: please include this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- HTML PART -->
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="fname" />
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<!-- END HTML PART -->

<!-- PHP FORM SUBMIT PART -->
<?php 
  if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $fname = $_POST['fname']; //form field name


    //send email
    $to = "somebody@example.com";
    $subject = "HTML email";
    $message = "Your details";
    $message.= "Firstname: $fname";

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    $f = fopen(ABSPATH . "data.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = json_encode($message);
    $txt .= "\n";
    fwrite($f, $txt);
    fclose($f);


    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

  }
?>
<!-- END PHP FORM SUBMIT PART -->
```

Comment: Is that gonna be different ?

Comment: like I have to delete that HTML file up there and replace it ?

Comment: No you don't need to delete Html file please change html file to php file only and use all the html inside the php file.

Comment: so, how to make the button work, how to add that PHP code init

Comment: only important part is php form submit code, you can use all html tags and anything in the PHP file, just change index.html to index.php

Comment: Now I have added comments on the code, maybe now you can understand better.

Comment: data.txt is just a txt file

Comment: does it contain the inputs ?

Comment: can I change .txt to .csi ?

Comment: Yes you change the file name

Comment: Yes the above example contains the input.

Comment: umm, there's 2 $message, but one of them includes a dot $message.

Comment: and 2 $txt, one ends with space and dot , $txt .

Comment: why does it include these dots ?

Comment: I have appended data to the file. it will not overwrite other data of the file